# Не читает первый символ с файла

Tags: java

Помогите, у меня проблема с чтением первого символа из файла.
Вот код:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
               InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/2.txt"),"Cp1252"));
                  int symbol = reader.read();
 while ((reader.ready()) ) 
            {
                    String c3; 
                    symbol = reader.read();
      System.out.println( symbol);
    }
```

Файл:

```
452
3
4

s
7
```

Выводит:

```
53
50
13
10
51
13
10
52
13
10
13
10
115
13
10
55
```

А должно:

```
52
53
50
13
10
51
13
10
52
13
10
13
10
115
13
10
55
```

Может знает кто, в чом проблема?

Comment: до  цикла while я ничо неделаю и на щот формата файла то он записан в кодировке анси и програма выводит код етих символов. 10 ето \r а 13 ето\n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не понятно по поводу формата файла и ожиданий, но проблема кроется в вычитывании символа до цикла `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Причина в том, что читать символы и выводить их надо в цикле.
Рекоммендации:
1. Чтение символа и проверку можно делать прямо в условии цикла
2. Проверку на конец файла делать не через ready(), т.к. отрабатывает иногда некорректно, а через значение, возвращенное методом read(). Если конец файла, то вернет -1.
Вот код который будет работать:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
              InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/2.txt"),"Cp1252"));
int symbol = 0;
while ((symbol = reader.read()) != -1 ) 
{
    System.out.println( symbol);
}
```